# The column name is lost when imported

Tags: csv, sqlite

I have a csv file which i need to import to sql. So i did the following on the terminal :-

```
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .import nodes.csv nodes
```

At this point i successfully imported the csv file to sqlite

```
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE nodes(
  "id" TEXT,
  "lat" TEXT,
  "lon" TEXT,
  "user" TEXT,
  "uid" TEXT,
  "version" TEXT,
  "changeset" TEXT,
  " TEXTestamp
);
```

As you can see the last field which was supposed to be the timestamp has changed to something else. Can anyone help to find the cause of this problem ?

Comment: What OS are you using? What kind of new-line character does the CSV file use?

Comment: I'm using Windows and i'm not sure about the newline character. I wrote the csv file using csv module in python.The original data was in XML

Comment: Are you using the latest version of `sqlite3.exe`?

Comment: Yes, i am using the latest version

Comment: The CSV file contains a CR (13) character at the wrong place. Show the code that writes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating the respective table before importing it. Also i removed the header rows from the csv. Thanks for the help.